# Why is my pygame screen static?

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm writing a pygame program in which rectangles fall continuously from the top of the screen, and the player can move their rectangle around to catch them. The problem is, when I run the program, the rectangles don't fall on their own. They only fall when you begin to move the character, or when you enter some form of input. They stop falling when the input ends. Why is this happening? I feel like it might have to do with my FPS settings, but I've done similar programs before without this problem occurring. Can anybody tell me what's going on?

Thanks in advance

```
    `import pygame, sys,random,time
from pygame.locals import*

pygame.init()
mainClock=pygame.time.Clock()

WINDOWWIDTH=400
WINDOWHEIGHT=400
windowSurface=pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH,WINDOWHEIGHT ),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Input with Falling Food')

BLACK=(0,0,0)
GREEN=(0,255,0)
WHITE=(255,255,255)

MOVESPEED=20

FOODSIZEMAX=30
FOODSIZEMIN=10

FOODMOVESPEED=30

foodCounter=0
NEWFOOD=5

player=pygame.Rect(300,100,50,50)
foods=[]
for i in range(10):
    FOODSIZE=random.randint(FOODSIZEMIN,FOODSIZEMAX)
    foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0,WINDOWWIDTH-FOODSIZE),0,FOODSIZE,FOODSIZE))

moveLeft=False
moveRight=False
moveUp=False
moveDown=False



while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT or event.key==ord('a'):
                moveRight=False
                moveLeft=True
            if event.key==K_RIGHT or event.key==ord('d'):
                moveLeft=False
                moveRight=True
            if event.key==K_UP or event.key==ord('w'):
                moveDown=False
                moveUp=True
            if event.key==K_DOWN or event.key==ord('s'):
                moveUp=False
                moveDown=True
        if event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key==K_LEFT or event.key==ord('a'):
                moveLeft=False
            if event.key==K_RIGHT or event.key==ord('d'):
                moveRight=False
            if event.key==K_UP or event.key==ord('w'):
                moveUp=False
            if event.key==K_DOWN or event.key==ord('s'):
                moveDown=False
            if event.key==ord('x'):
                player.top=random.randint(0,WINDOWHEIGHT-player.height)
                player.left=random.randint(0,WINDOWWIDTH-player.width)

        if event.type==MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            foods.append(pygame.Rect(event.pos[0],event.pos[1],FOODSIZE,FOODSIZE))

        foodCounter+=1
        if foodCounter>=NEWFOOD:
            foodCounter=0
            FOODSIZE=random.randint(FOODSIZEMIN,FOODSIZEMAX)
            foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0,WINDOWWIDTH-FOODSIZE),0,FOODSIZE,FOODSIZE))

        windowSurface.fill(BLACK)

        if moveDown and player.bottom<WINDOWHEIGHT:
            player.top+=MOVESPEED
        if moveUp and player.top>0:
            player.top-=MOVESPEED
        if moveLeft and player.left>0:
            player.left-=MOVESPEED
        if moveRight and player.right<WINDOWWIDTH:
            player.right+=MOVESPEED

        pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface,WHITE,player)

        for i in range(len(foods)):
            foods[i].top+=FOODMOVESPEED


        for food in foods[:]:
            if player.colliderect(food):
                foods.remove(food)
        for food in foods[:]:
            if food.top>=WINDOWHEIGHT:
                foods.remove(food)

        for i in range(len(foods)):
            pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface,GREEN,foods[i])

        pygame.display.update()
        #mainClock.tick(40)
        #time.sleep(0.02)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break your main loop code out of the `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop.

That is, everything you want to run every time the clock ticks (not just when the game receives input events) should be outside that loop, just in the main `while` loop.

At the very least, for the food to move:

```
    for i in range(len(foods)):
        foods[i].top+=FOODMOVESPEED
```

Needs to be taken out.